# Webpack ES6 modules circular dependencies when using index files

Tags: javascript, webpack, circular-dependency, es6-modules

I have a big project, I try to refactor to ES6 modules right now.

To make further development easier, I wanted to introduce index files, which just export all modules within the directory:

**index.js:**

```
export { default as ModuleA } from './moduleA'
export { default as ModuleB } from './moduleB'
export { default as ModuleC } from './moduleC'
```

**moduleA.js:**

```
import { ModuleB } from './index'
```

**moduleB.js:**

```
import { ModuleC } from './index'

ModuleC.doSomething()
```

**moduleC.js:**

```
export default {
  doSomething: () => {}
}
```

Starting point is `ModuleA`.

The problem is, that in `ModuleB` `ModuleC` is undefined, so `doSomething` can't be executed.
I suspect some issues with circular dependencies, since `moduleB` tries to access the index again, which parses `moduleB` before `moduleC`.

Is it just not possible to do this, or is there another solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is that ModuleC has not been exported by the time that ModuleB is exported and runs, and since ModuleC is a requirement of ModuleB, it can't run. If I were you, I would just export each of them from their own files, and when you import them, import them from their own files instead of index.js.

**Example**

**ModuleA.js:**

```
import { ModuleB } from 'moduleB.js'
    export default {
      // Your code here
}
```

**ModuleB.js**

```
import { ModuleC } from 'moduleC.js'
moduleC.doSomething();
```

**ModuleC.js**

```
export default {
    doSomething: () => {
      // Your code
    }
}
```

And finally, since ModuleA is the entry point from index.js, just import it into index.js and run what you need to run.

Answer (score 4):

Alright. Solved it.

The problem ist, that when `ModuleB` tries to import `ModuleC` from the index, the index will be parsed again and will see `ModuleB` before it can reach `ModuleC`.
It seems to work with only two modules, since the index file doesn't get reparsed, I think.

The solution:
Import modules, which try to load other modules from the index file at last.

So **index.js** should look like this:

```
export { default as ModuleA } from './moduleA'
export { default as ModuleC } from './moduleC'
export { default as ModuleB } from './moduleB'
```